# How to remove f1 from returned column when using row_to_json in postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am using row_to_json to transform the columns into json. 
this is my query:

```
 Select row_to_json(row(func1('cust_1')));
```

note func1 is an sql function that takes one varchar and returns 3 floats

this query is returning:

```
{"f1":{"col1":0,"col2":0,"col3":0}}
```

What I want is the object inside f1, I want the query to return only this:

```
{"col1":0,"col2":0,"col3":0}
```

how can I do this ?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: `Select row_to_json(row(func1('cust_1')))->>'f1';`

Comment: @jarlh I am using Postgresql, I tagged mysql since it is similar and maybe they can help

Comment: @VaoTsun Thank you that is what I needed

Comment: `select to_json(x.*) from func1('cust_1') as x;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [Get JSON object field as text](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
Select row_to_json(row(func1('cust_1')))->>'f1';
```